# What "theoretical problems" are associated with Zero-inflated negative binomial models

Tags: model, negative-binomial-distribution, zero-inflation

I just finished a course in regression on count based outcomes. We studied various distributions such as the Poisson and Negative Binomial. Towards the end of the course, we discussed Zero-Inflated Poisson and Zero-Inflated Negative Binomial.

Now I am hoping to learn a bit more about these during the summer. During the course, the lecturer mentioned "However, there are theoretical problems associated with use of the ZINB model, so it is frequently hard to justify."

OK, so, my questions are:

1) Are there any recommended sources to read more about issues with ZINB models?
2) Suppose that for a given data set, based on all available model fit metrics ZINB is clearly the best fit to the data. In this case, is it still problematic to use it?

Comment: Perhaps it is too late to ask your instructor. This kind of question really makes me wonder why they were not identified and addressed in class. Moreover, are these problems genuine barriers to using such models, which could prove quite useful?

Comment: if i understand correctly he is away for the summer, possibly more, on sabbatical.